# Unble to download pyinstaller with pip for python 3.4, 3.6

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I've never downloaded with pip before so I might be doing something dumb, but I've looked at tutorials.
I'm installing with pip in cmd, using the path to python34/Scripts (which is where pip is).
I'm getting the console output:

```
C:/Python34/Scripts>pip install pyinstaller
Downloading/unpacking pyinstaller
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement 
pyinstaller
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pyinstaller
Storing debug log for failure [...]
```

I tried using pip3:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip3 install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.3.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in 
c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Collecting pefile>=2017.8.1 (from pyinstaller)
Using cached pefile-2017.11.5.tar.gz
Collecting macholib>=1.8 (from pyinstaller)
Using cached macholib-1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting future (from pyinstaller)
Using cached future-0.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting pypiwin32 (from pyinstaller)
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting altgraph>=0.15 (from macholib>=1.8->pyinstaller)
Using cached altgraph-0.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->pyinstaller)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->pyinstaller) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from 
pypiwin32->pyinstaller)
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223

Is this because python 3.4 is not supported, maybe? I'll try downloading 3.6

I tried downloading 3.6, for some reason it ended up at `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6`
and I cannot find pip anywhere near. Can i just drag the pip from 3.4 to 3.6?

Tried dragging it over, then running `pip3 install pyinstaller` from the directory `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6`. Got the same error as with pip3 in the 3.4 directory.

At this point I'm at a loss. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, you cannot just drag the pip from 3.4 to 3.6. But 3.6 should have installed and updated the `py` launcher. If you just run `py` from your command prompt, do you get Python 3.6? If so, `py -m pip install pyinstaller` will install it for 3.6.

Comment: Also, do you still need Python 3.4? Your life will be easier if you uninstall it and only have one Python around.

Comment: Finally, just to confirm: you were 100% right about why it wasn’t working: the current version of pyinstaller requires a recent version of pywin32, and pywin32 dropped support for 3.4, so you can’t get a recent-enough version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple Python installations (except for the simple case of one 2.7 and one 3.x), and you don’t want to use virtual environments, the simplest solution is to not try to run scripts like `pip` and `2to3` directly, but instead run them via `-m`. That way, you only have to know how to run Python itself for each installation, and you automatically know how to run everything else. For example, if you run Python 3.6 like this:

```
 python36
```

… then you run the copy of `pip` that comes with Python 3.6 like this:

```
python36 -m pip
```

That way you’re guaranteed that it’s running the copy of `pip` that you want, using the version of Python that you want, so everything gets installed into the site packages for that version of Python.

On Windows, the recommended way of dealing with multiple Python installations is the `py` launcher. When you installed 3.6, it should have installed the launcher if not present, and configured it to default to 3.6. So, you can run Python 3.6 like this:

```
py
```

You should verify that this actually runs Python 3.6. But, assuming it does, you can run its `pip` like this:

```
py -m pip
```

---

However, are you sure you even want to manage multiple Python installations? It’s unlikely that you have code that works in 3.4 but not 3.6. (If you’d installed a bunch of packages for 3.4 you’d need to freeze a requirements file and install it for 3.6, but since you’ve never used `pip` before, that’s not an issue.) So if you just uninstall 3.4, all of this confusion won’t even come up.

Although you still may want `py -m pip`. This way, you don’t have to add stuff to your PATH or `cd` into specific directories; `py` should just be always available.

Also, if you *do* want multiple Python installations, are you sure you don’t want to use virtual environments? That way, whichever environment you currently have activated, `python`, `pip`, etc. all come from that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing wheels directly from this site, which hosts precompiled wheels for windows, including pyinstaller:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This was good advice a few years ago, but now the same precompiled wheels are available on PyPI and installable by `pip`.

Comment: @abarnert There are no pywin32 binary wheels for Python 3.4 at PyPI; there are at Gohlke's site.